# How do I stop sound on mouseout when hovering over an image?

Tags: mouseout

```
<head>
var Start = new Audio("MySound.mp3");
</head>


<body>
<div>
<img src="MyPicture.png" width="400" height="300" onmouseover="Start.play();" onmouseout="Start.pause;"></img>
</div>
</body>
```

When hovering over the image the sound plays correctly but when I mouseout the sound continues playing? Not too sure why that is.

Comment: Did you try to add `()` after `Start.pause`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from `onmouseout="Start.pause;">` to `onmouseout="Start.pause();">`. You missed the parenthesis in the pause function

Comment: Please do not answer questions where the sole error is a typo. Rather, flag such questions as off-topic